# How i can write to the console events together with the current time?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write to the console events together with the current time and date, but the time does not change with events. How can I update the variable of time every second?

```
var cde = function(){
    var dte=new Date(),
        mce=dte.getMonth()+1,
        day=dte.getDate(),
        hrs=dte.getHours(),
        mns=dte.getMinutes(),
        sec=dte.getSeconds();
if(mce<10){mce='0'+mce}
    if(day<10){day='0'+day}
    if(hrs<10){hrs='0'+hrs}
    if(mns<10){mns='0'+mns}
    if(sec<10){sec='0'+sec}

return 
'['+day+'.'+mce+'.'+dte.getFullYear()+'::'+hrs+':'+mns+':'+sec+']';

}
```

Comment: wrap this in a function and call it when the even happen , and it will update , but if your asking how to display time each second then thats other thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new date every time you make a log.
When you make a date in JS...

```
var date = new Date();
```

... no matter how many times you call `date`, it's still going to be equal to the exact millisecond it was created (based on the user's system-clock).

Wrap what you've got there in a function, instead of an immediately-invoked function, and call it.

```
console.log( cde() /*, stuff */ );
```